# How to remove a directory and its descendents at once in shell?

Tags: shell

I tried to delete a directory which contains other directories, but it shows "rmdir: failed to remove './will': Directory not empty"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete you need `rm`  and "-rf" for recursive force

```
rm -rf yourdirectoryname
```

Comment: thanks, and if i want to be aware of deleting some important files in the directories, which command do you recommend?

Comment: @SeifBoukhatem that Philosophical question , "important" it's defined by you which is and which is not otherwise all folder the same and as well there's "System file" so take care before using it 
Specially in System dir

Comment: @SeifBoukhatem : You could add the `-i` switch to `rm`, so you can decide for each file, whether or not it is important to you....